# Android BitcoinJ set up error: "Expected the service [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED"

Tags: java, android, gradle, bitcoin-testnet, bitcoinjs-lib

Issue: I have two classes MainActivity and BitcoinConfig (see below). Can someone please help me fix issues I'm having syncing the blockchain?

The AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle files are given below.

Errors:  I’ve attached the full logcat with the getCause info below, but one of the main errors is:

*W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the service [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED (line 50 kit.awaitSync() in the BitcoinConfig class)*

Thanks (sorry if this is obvious this is all new to me)!

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
    <code>
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
       private BitcoinConfig btcService;
    
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           btcService = new BitcoinConfig();
           btcService.settingUp();
       }
    }
    </code>
```

**BITCOINCONFIG**

```
<code>
import android.util.Log;
import org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey;
import org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters;
import org.bitcoinj.core.listeners.DownloadProgressTracker;
import org.bitcoinj.kits.WalletAppKit;
import org.bitcoinj.params.RegTestParams;
import org.bitcoinj.params.TestNet3Params;
import org.bitcoinj.utils.BriefLogFormatter;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

public class BitcoinConfig {

   private NetworkParameters params;
   private WalletAppKit kit;
   private File walletPath;
   private static final String TAG = BitcoinConfig.class.getSimpleName();

   public BitcoinConfig() {
   }

   public void settingUp() {
       params = TestNet3Params.get();
       Log.d(TAG, "getting network");
       BriefLogFormatter.init();

       Log.d(TAG, "creating wallet");
       kit = new WalletAppKit(params, new File("/home/annab"), "UserWallet") {
           @Override
           protected void onSetupCompleted() {
               if (wallet().getImportedKeys().size() < 1)
                   wallet().importKey(new ECKey());
               Log.d(TAG, "in on set up");
           }
       };


       if (params == RegTestParams.get()) {
           kit.connectToLocalHost();
           Log.d(TAG, "in connect to regtestnet");
       }
       kit.setBlockingStartup(false);
       Log.d(TAG, "setBlockingStartup(false)");
       try {
           kit.startAsync();
           Log.d(TAG, "startAsync()");
       } catch(Throwable t){
           Log.d(TAG, "startAsync error"); // never goes here
           t.getCause();
       }
       try {
           kit.awaitRunning(); // error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the service  [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED
           Log.d(TAG, "awaitRunning()");
       } catch (Throwable t) {
           System.out.println("awaitingRunning exception");  // goes here
           t.getCause();
       }
   }
}
<code>
```

**build.gradle(:module)**

```
buildscript {

   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
   }
}


allprojects {

   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
   }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
}


android {

   compileSdkVersion 31
   buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"


   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.walletexample"
       minSdkVersion 23
       targetSdkVersion 31
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }


   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }

   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}


dependencies {
   // already here
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
   implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0"


   // BitcoinJ SDK
   implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.15.10'

   // logging
   implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
   implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'

   implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<code>
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.example.walletexample">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:exported ="true"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.WalletExample">
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>*
</code>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
10/30 14:02:39: Launching 'MainActivity' on samsung SM-G9730.
Install successfully finished in 192 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.walletexample/com.example.walletexample.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 15603 on device 'samsung-sm_g9730-R28M50DX0ML'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from the application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/e.walletexampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getConfiguration()Landroid/content/res/Configuration; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getDisplayMetrics()Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->isInDexDisplay()Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getDisplayMetrics(ILandroid/view/DisplayAdjustments;)Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getAdjustedDisplay(ILandroid/view/DisplayAdjustments;)Landroid/view/Display; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getResources(Landroid/os/IBinder;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;ILandroid/content/res/Configuration;Landroid/content/res/CompatibilityInfo;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/util/List;)Landroid/content/res/Resources; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getResources(Landroid/os/IBinder;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;ILandroid/content/res/Configuration;Landroid/content/res/CompatibilityInfo;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/res/Resources; (blacklist, linking, denied)
W/e.walletexampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getResources(Landroid/os/IBinder;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;ILandroid/content/res/Configuration;Landroid/content/res/CompatibilityInfo;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/res/Resources; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->rebaseKeyForActivity(Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/content/res/ResourcesKey;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->createResources(Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/content/res/ResourcesKey;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Landroid/content/res/Resources; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->rebaseKeyForActivity(Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/content/res/ResourcesKey;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->createResources(Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/content/res/ResourcesKey;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Landroid/content/res/Resources; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->invalidatePath(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/res/ResourcesKey;->isPathReferenced(Ljava/lang/String;)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mCachedApkAssets:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/e.walletexampl: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mCachedApkAssets:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$ApkKey;->path:Ljava/lang/String; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mCachedApkAssets:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/res/ApkAssets;->close()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mCachedApkAssets:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$ApkKey;->path:Ljava/lang/String; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mCachedApkAssets:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/res/ApkAssets;->close()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->isSameResourcesOverrideConfig(Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/e.walletexampl: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$ActivityResources;->overrideConfig:Landroid/content/res/Configuration; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$ActivityResources;->overrideConfig:Landroid/content/res/Configuration; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$ActivityResources;->overrideConfig:Landroid/content/res/Configuration; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/res/Configuration;->diffPublicOnly(Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->leaveLogCurrentState()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getResourcesHashList()Ljava/lang/String; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->overrideTokenDisplayAdjustments(Landroid/os/IBinder;Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$ActivityResources;->activityResources:Ljava/util/ArrayList; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/e.walletexampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/res/Resources;->overrideDisplayAdjustments(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->setDisplayPolicyResources(Landroid/content/res/Resources;I)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mSavedLogs:Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$EvictingArrayQueue; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mFormatter:Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$EvictingArrayQueue;-><init>(Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;I)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mDPResHash:I (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mDPImplHash:I (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->save(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->updateResourcesForActivity(Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/content/res/Configuration;IZ)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getOrCreateActivityResourcesStructLocked(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Landroid/app/ResourcesManager$ActivityResources; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/e.walletexampl: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
    Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
I/studio.deploy: Finished instrumenting
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication()++ app=com.example.walletexample
D/LoadedApk: LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext=android.app.ContextImpl@a359449 appContext.mOpPackageName=com.example.walletexample appContext.mBasePackageName=com.example.walletexample appContext.mPackageInfo=android.app.LoadedApk@574914e
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication() -- skipGraphicsSupport=false
I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 4e552d6, I7befcd4846
    Build Date                       : 04/04/21
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.9.1.R1.11.00.00.604.073
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
    Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
I/AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
I/DecorView: [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
I/DecorView: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@76c355f[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false, hasWindowControllerCallback=true
D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@76c355f[]
W/e.walletexampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.walletexampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/System.err: [main] INFO org.bitcoinj.crypto.LinuxSecureRandom - Secure randomness will be read from /dev/urandom only.
D/BitcoinConfig: getting network
D/BitcoinConfig: creating wallet
W/System.err: [main] INFO org.bitcoinj.core.Context - Creating bitcoinj 0.15.10 context.
D/BitcoinConfig: setBlockingStartup(false)
D/BitcoinConfig: startAsync()
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the service  [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED
W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.checkCurrentState(AbstractService.java:366)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.awaitRunning(AbstractService.java:302)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService.awaitRunning(AbstractIdleService.java:163)
        at com.example.walletexample.BitcoinConfig.settingUp(BitcoinConfig.java:50)
        at com.example.walletexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3800)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4003)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create directory /home/annab
        at org.bitcoinj.kits.WalletAppKit.startUp(WalletAppKit.java:292)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:60)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:119)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: 'bf476b5', fd=79
I/ViewRootImpl@3c1062f[MainActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@76c355f TM=true
I/ViewRootImpl@3c1062f[MainActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x32ebee6 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1810 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x4f58c27 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1117 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1820 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
I/ViewRootImpl@3c1062f[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2280) new=(0,0,1080,2280) req=(0,0)8 dur=17 res=0x1 s={false 0} ch=false fn=-1
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```